# Robotframework PATCH request

Tags: robotframework

I want to test a PATCH Request , however i have a 400 bad request

[image]

so if you have some idea ! i'll take them all :D thank you

Comment: Hi! Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.

Comment: have you tried removing the quotes around `"PATCH"`? Also, what library are you using? And finally, please don't post an image of code; post the actual code.

Comment: yes i did ! if i remove them  , it says "503 SERVICE UNAVAILABLE " .

Comment: i use httplibrary.HTTP

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found that PATCH is not implemented in the released version of httplibrary.

You can add code from this [pull request](https://github.com/peritus/robotframework-httplibrary/pull/28/commits/4857fd423d2344b9e5684f9e733f269cdff45da7) in **init**.py under the httplibrary folder.

Comment: Seems to me the first paragraph alone qualifies this as an attempted answer.